# Relationship between the g-factor and the gyromagnetic ratio?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

From what I have read the g-factor and the gyromagnetic ratio are two different quantities.

It appears to me that the gyromagnetic ratio is the ratio between (any) angular momentum and the magnetic dipole moment that, that angular momentum produces. e.g. 
$$\vec \mu_s=\gamma_s \vec S$$
$$\vec \mu_l=\gamma_l \vec L$$
Where $\gamma_s$ and $\gamma_L$ would both be counted as gyromagnetic ratios (is this correct?). The g-factor seems to have another definition (one that I can't yet clarify, and seeming to involve the Bohr magneton). So what is the relationship between the g-factor and the gyromagnetic ratio?

Comment: your understanding of $\gamma$ is correct. In general, $\gamma$ has units of chage/mass, so we may write $\gamma= (g/2) e/m$, where $g$ is a dimensionless number. This is just convention: $e$ and $m$ can be any two numbers with units of charge and mass (though in practice $e$ is always the charge of the electron). In atomic physics, we take $m=m_e$ (mass of the electron), and in nuclear physics, $m=m_p$ (mass of the proton). In astrophysics we could even take $m$ the mass of a planet, and $e$ its charge.(1/2)

Comment: (2/2)  The number $g$, which value depends on the specific problem at hand, is called the $g-$factor, and is just like $\gamma$, but without units. Note that in general, $g=\mathcal O(1)$. For example, $g_l=1$, and $g_s\approx 2$. For more complex examples, $g$ could be a function of $m$, $e$, or other parameters of the problem, but it is always dimensionless (and we like dimensionless parameters, because they measure the strength of the couplings).